# Combining GET and POST parts in Happstack route filters

Tags: haskell, filter, routes, happstack

I'm trying to implement a simple request handler using Happstack:

```
main :: IO ()
main = simpleHTTP nullConf app

app :: ServerPart Response
app = msum [
             dir "hello" $ method GET  >> helloGet
           , dir "hello" $ method POST >> helloPost
           ]
```

How can I achieve something similar without repeating the `dir "hello"`?

This,

```
app :: ServerPart Response
app = msum [
             dir "hello" $ do
                method GET  >> helloGet
                method POST >> helloPost
           , okResponse home
           ]
```

will only "fall through" to the default part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app :: ServerPart Response
app = msum [
             dir "hello" $ (method GET >> helloGet) <|> (method POST >> helloPost)
           , okResponse home
           ]
```

..  Assuming `ServerPart` has the appropriate `Alternative` instance. If it's missing for some reason, you can replace `(<|>)` with `mplus`. The main idea here is that you're just nesting one routing combinator inside another.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close already:

```
app :: ServerPart Response
app = msum [
             dir "hello" $ do
                method GET  >> helloGet
                method POST >> helloPost
           , okResponse home
           ]
```

You just need an extra nested `msum`:

```
app :: ServerPart Response
app = msum [
             dir "hello" $
                msum [ method GET  >> helloGet
                     , method POST >> helloPost
                     ]
           , okResponse home
           ]
```

As someone else suggested you can also use `<|>` or `mplus` or other functions related to `Alternative` and `MonadPlus`.

- jeremy

Comment: Thanks. This is becoming a bit more clear now. I have to read up on my msum, mplus and friends.